# Algorithm for deriving enum value from sensor values?

Tags: algorithm, enums

I have a set of sensor values, all floats from 0 to 1. Is there a well known algorithm to derive the most likely enum value from a set of sensor values given a data set of known correlations?

For example:

Known:

- 0, 0.7, 1, RightsideUp
- 1, 0.2, 0.9, UpsideDown
- 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, UpsideDown
- ...

Unknown:

0.6, 0.1, 0.8, ????

Optionally, is there an algorithm that supports weighted inputs and produces a confidence value for each enum value?

Comment: What you are looking for is a [Classifier](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier), which is a common technique in the field of [Machine Learning](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) to do this.  You would train it on your known values and then use it as a classifier to classify new values.